# What is the new equivalent of DOMNodeInserted?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

The [`DOMNodeInserted` event has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and all Mutation Events have been replaced with mutation observers.

But, [within mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) there are only config options for watching mutations to the nodes attributes, content, and children.  Nothing about a mutation to it's placement in the DOM tree.

There is one "solution" I can think of which is to observe everything from document.body down searching for the one mutation which is my target node being added, but that's a pretty awful way of doing anything.

So what is the expected way to replace the deprecated DOMNodeInserted with Mutation Observers?

EDIT: found possible duplicate [What is the most efficient way of detecting when an element with a particular ID is inserted in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313108/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-detecting-when-an-element-with-a-particular-id?rq=1)

Once Again, SO: [The searchbar works better with Tags than Questions. Explaining this could reduce duplicates and save users time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336082/the-searchbar-works-better-with-tags-than-questions-explaining-this-could-reduc?noredirect=1#comment403450_336082)

Below is some code where you can see that none of the available mutation observer config options respond to the element being added to the page:

```js
var addMe = document.createElement("div");
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log(mutations);
});
observer.observe(addMe, config);

function appendAddMe() {
  document.body.appendChild(addMe);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #969;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="appendAddMe()">Append addMe</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really consider this to be *the* answer to the question, but I'd like to share it anyways because it's better than nothing.

This question has some good answers: [What is the most efficient way of detecting when an element with a particular ID is inserted in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313108/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-detecting-when-an-element-with-a-particular-id?rq=1)

In particular, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25107064/4808079
from [schettino72](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64444/schettino72)

> iframe elements trigger load/unoad events. You can insert a dumb iframe in the element you want to watch... And trigger a 'load' event in the original element yourself.

```
function watch($ele){
    var $iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    $iframe.style.display = 'none';
    $ele.appendChild($iframe);
    $iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){
      var event = new CustomEvent('load');
      $ele.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
```

I would still like to keep this question open as this is a hack and not a true answer.  DOMNodeInserted was probably not deprecated so everyone could do it this way instead.